# Elegant way to find a specific text in python

Tags: python

Is there a more beautiful way to exclude strings from a text than this? Sorry I am fairly new to programming.
For example, I want to find bettext[1] by searching through the list of strings.

```
bettext[0] = '1. HL Over + / Under'
bettext[1] = 'Over + / Under'
bettext[2] = 'H2 Over + / Under'

excl_str_1 = "1. HL Over + / Under"
excl_str_2 = "2. HL Over + / Under"
excl_str_3 = "corners"
excl_str_4 = "yellow cards"
excl_str_5 = "1st"
excl_str_6 = "H2"


if not (excl_str_1) in bettext:
    if not (excl_str_2) in bettext:
        if not (excl_str_3) in bettext:
            if not (excl_str_4) in bettext:
                if not (excl_str_5) in bettext:
                    if not (excl_str_6) in bettext:
                        if (search_str) in bettext:
                            print(bettext)
```

Sorry if it's already been answered, I tried two different but similar stackoverflow answers and tried to apply them to this code but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is!

For starters, put all the excluded strings in a list because you are going to do the same thing with them. Then use `all` to make sure something is true for every item of this list:

```
excl_strings = ["1. HL Over + / Under", "2. HL Over + / Under", "corners", "yellow cards", "1st", "H2"

if all(excl_string not in bettext for excl_string in excl_strings):
   if search_str in bettext:
       print(bettext)
```

Comment: Thanks guys! The almost exact same answer at the same time :)

Comment: This answer worked exactly like I wanted! Thank you so much and for not downvoting me :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use a container for your strings, not n variables. I suggest a set because `in` checks will run in constant time.

```
string_check = {"1. HL Over + / Under", "2. HL Over + / Under", "corners", ...}
```

(The set contains `excl_str_1`, `excl_str_2`, ..., `search_str`.)

Next, use the `any` builtin:

```
if not any(s in string_check for s in bettext):
    # do something
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
for s in bettext:
    if s in string_check:
        break
else:
    # do something
```

The `for/else` may look weird. Mind-parse it as `for/nobreak`.

Comment: Thanks guys! The almost exact same answer at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

There are utils to shorten your code, particularly you can use a list of strings to exclude and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in your condition:

```
excl_strings = ["1. HL Over + / Under",
                "2. HL Over + / Under",
                "corners",
                "yellow cards",
                "1st",
                "H2"]

if search_str in bettext and not any(s in bettext for s in excl_strings):
    print(bettext)
```